# Transition both ways between text elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two paragraphs (lets say with id "p1" and "p2")

I would like to transition from one to another when a link is clicked, and vice versa when a different link is clicked. They are located on the same page but only one is displayed at a time (using javascript to hide one then display the other when the link is clicked).

Both paragraphs have "hidden page" as their classes.

Would the css resemble something like this?

```
.hidden {
    opacity: 0;
    display: none;
    transition: opacity 1s linear;
}

.page { 
    transition: opacity 1s linear;  
    opacity: 1;
}
```

I know it's not that but would it be something similar?

EDIT:
Link to the gist of the css, js, and html files

https://gist.github.com/EricHanLiu/a4b09862f2d25b6c6e5f

edited out some things like name phone# email etc, but the main focus of is on the two paragraphs in the middle

Comment: More or less, you also need a keyframe animation transition, using **from:to**

Comment: can you make some codepen? or image?

Comment: Instead of pasting some huge gists, you have the ability to create a small and verifiable code snippet right within your question. Do so.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to fade in one paragraph when clicking on a link and faded the other one out if it is visible then you can do something like the following:

[Live Preview](http://codepen.io/larryjoelane/pen/mPRjxJ)

**HTML:**

```
<a id="first" href="#p1">1</a> <a id="second" href="#p2">2</a>

<div class="fadeIn">
  <p id="p1" class="hidden">I am the first paragraph.</p>
</div>

<div class="fadeIn">
  <p id="p2" class="hidden">I am the second paragraph.</p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
}

/*fade in transition css below*/

.fadeIn p {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 2.0s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 2.0s ease-in;
  -o-transition: opacity 2.0s ease-in;
}

.fadeIn p.clicked {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
//helper function to select the element by id
function $(id){

  return document.getElementById(id);

}

//on click event for first 
$("first").addEventListener("click",function(event){

 //prevent page refresh or navigation
 event.preventDefault();



  $("p1").classList.add("clicked");

  $("p2").classList.remove("clicked")

});


//on click event for second
$("second").addEventListener("click",function(event){

 //prevent page refresh or navigation
 event.preventDefault();

  $("p1").classList.remove("clicked");

  $("p2").classList.add("clicked");


});
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you need two links to trigger the two paragraphs, respectively.
Here's my simple solution to your problem. I am not that sure that this is what you are looking for. But hopefully this helps!

```
<div>
    <p class="show" id="p1">Paragraph 1</p>
    <p class="hidden" id="p2">Paragraph 2</p>
    <a href="#" id="sb1">Show Paragraph 1</a>
    <a href="#" id="sb2">Show Paragraph 2</a>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var sb1 = document.getElementById('sb1');
    var sb2 = document.getElementById('sb2');
    var p1 = document.getElementById('p1');
    var p2 = document.getElementById('p2');
    sb1.addEventListener('click', function() {
      p1.classList.remove('hidden');
      p1.classList.add('show');
      p2.classList.remove('show');
      p2.classList.add('hidden');
    });

    sb2.addEventListener('click', function() {
      p1.classList.remove('show');
      p1.classList.add('hidden');
      p2.classList.remove('hidden');
      p2.classList.add('show');
    });
  </script>
```

In the script above, I just switched the respective classes on the two paragraphs.

There a lot of solution to this, you can use jQuery to simplify this solution.

Comment: that's not what i'm looking for, I'm looking for a transition effect. I'll edit my post with a gist